# How to scale the window in plan visualization?

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [PlanVis](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/PlanVis).

I run:

```
  svn co http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest knowrob
  rosmake
  rosrun rosprolog rosprolog mod_vis
  register_ros_package(knowrob_actions).
  owl_parse('/opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_actions/owl/serve_drink.owl', false, false, true).
  planvis_create(Pv).
  planvis_load('http://www.roboearth.org/kb/serve_drink.owl#ServeADrink',$Pv).
```

And it shows:

[image: image description]

How to scale the window (in this example is serve a drink) which my cursor pointed?

It's too big to show in one screen.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41046/how-to-scale-the-window-in-plan-visualization?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, but how to scale windows is no ROS-related problem. The visualization window can be scaled using whatever mechanism your window manager supports (maximize to screen, drag the border with the mouse to resize, ...)

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-09**:
What I mean is not the Java program's window. I means the inside 'serve a drink' window. Can I scale it? I can't find any way to scale. Thank you~

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-08-09**:
You can't scale it, but you can shift it around holding the right mouse button pressed.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-09**:
Yeah, I found I only can move it. Is there any way to scale it or how to patch it? Thank you~